# How to configure the Android's default email client programatically

Tags: android, email, email-client

I have been doing some research on configuring the IMAP/POP settings programmatically to the Android default Email client.
So, basically, I want the email ID, password and IMAP settings to be stored within the application, and when the app is launched, it should programatically configure the Android's email client.
Any help regarding the same would be highly appreciated!

Thanks,
Nithin

Comment: Man i have same requirements, i want to ask is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some research on this, and it is not possible, unless you implement your own email client like K9. That is only within your app, but not the Android's default email client.

Comment: Hi, I am developing an application (Client/ Server demo app), where I will send an Email account (configured) to android app, and then my application will setup/ add new email account to Android device. I gone through your question and answer, and reading about K9, can you pliz help me to guide me that how can I do this? My requirement is same as yours.